# Clarify the values for delete/undelete votes on 10k tools page

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, wording, vote-to-undelete

There are items with delete/undelete votes on [10k tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days). But the values specified there are not clear:

> [image]

Actually it's relate to number of votes already given (the first one), and the number of votes that still awaiting to proceed (in the parentheses). Can we clarify it somehow in text form to make it more obvious?

Comment: This page, like many parts of the site (especially pages only accessible by mods/high-rep users), is just really old and its design hasn't been touched in ages. I imagine that if it is reworked at some point, it'll be more substantially redesigned beyond just this change. (I'm guessing the number on the left is the post score, and the number in parentheses is the number of delete/undelete votes? Or vice versa.)

Comment: @V2Blast one is how many delete/undelete votes it currently has, the other how many it needs to be deleted/undeleted. Can't remember which is which exactly but maybe left is current count, right is how many more are needed.

Comment: The numbers of delete votes that are still required do show a description when hovered over.